# How to solve the error - PCC-F-02144, CMD-LINE: Blank characters are not allowed on either side of an equ al sign (=)

Tags: c, linux, oracle-pro-c

Please help me suggesting how to solve the below error

PCC-F-02144, CMD-LINE: Blank characters are not allowed on either side of an equ
al sign (=)

This is coming while compiling a C source code via make command on Linux platform. 
I am finding it difficult to trace from which line exactly this error is coming.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How could we know? You don't provide any source code, nor makefile nor nothing.

Comment: It is not coming from the code, but from your compilation instructions.

Comment: If it by any chance an Oracle Pro*C source file?

Answer (score 1):

Your Makefile is trying to compile Oracle Pro*C source files into common C files. For that it uses the `proc` compiler like

```
proc iname=some-file.pc oname=some-other-file.c
```

Note there are *no* spaces around the `=` signs. Your error happens when you write your command line like

```
proc iname =some-file.pc oname= some-other-file.c   <-- BAD! Produces PCC-F-02144
```

So look on your Makefiles for `proc` lines and check if there are spaces around the `=` signs.

Answer (score 0):

So look on your Makefiles for proc lines and check if there are any variables or macros assigned to the PROC which is either not set or not assigned.

eg:
$(PROCPLSFLAGS) $(PROC_INCLUDE)

PROC_INCLUDE=.$() $() $() // contains whatever include files you want to have. Please check the values of such variables and anywhere we miss out to allocate the value